# How do you return login form errors to the same page using PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I'm relatively new to PHP and have exhausted the internet trying to find an answer to this problem. I've looked at countless examples but people seem to very different login systems to mine and I have trouble deciphering it.

Here is my code so far:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Video for Education Log In</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>



<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        videoedu.edu    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="account.html" class="menua">Create Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html" class="menua">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<div id="page">

<div id="content">
    <h2>Video for Education helps you connect and share with the videos in your life.</h2>
    <h3>Upload Share Create Using video for your education purposes. Lecturers Welcome
    Upload Share Create Using video for your education purposes. Lecturers Welcome
    Upload Share Create Using video for your education purposes. Lecturers Welcome</h3>
    <div class= "form">
    <form name="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
        Username: <input type="text" name="myusername" id="myusername" class="textb"/><br />
        Password  :  <input type="password" name="mypassword" id="mypassword" class="textb"/><br />
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" id="login" class="texta" />
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**checklogin.php**

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "test";
$tbl_name = "members";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("Cannot connect.");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("Cannot select DB.");

$myusername=$_POST["myusername"];
$mypassword=$_POST["mypassword"];


    if ($myusername&&$mypassword)
    {

    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count == 1){
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword"); 
    header("location:login_success.php");
        }
    else 
        {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        }
    }

    else

    echo "You have left one or more fields blank.";

?>
```

**login_success.php**

```
<? 
session_start();
if( !isset( $_SESSION['myusername'] ) ){
header("location:account.html");
}

echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['myusername']." - You are now logged in.<br>";

echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>"
?>

<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

session_destroy();

echo "You have been logged out, <a href='index.php'>click here</a> to return."

?>
```

I have tried inserting this into index.html and changing the file name to index.php.

```
$submit = $_POST["login"];

if($submit)
{

}
```

...but it just constantly displays one of the errors ('Wrong username or password') down the bottom of the page at all times.

I want it so that if the user enters a wrong username or password, or leaves a required field blank, the error will pop up on the same page, instead of going to a new ugly, blank PHP page with the error message in the top left-hand corner.

Comment: Checking to required blanks is easier with JavaScript (jQuery or other frameworks work well). Before answering wrong username or password message, in which file (may be div) do you need to show that message? Clarify this, I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In checklogin.php, instead of echoing an error, use this:

```
die(header("location:index.html?loginFailed=true&reason=password"));
```

or something similar, and in your index.html page, just have PHP generate the HTML message, something like this:

```
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" id="login" class="texta" /><br /><br />
    <?php $reasons = array("password" => "Wrong Username or Password", "blank" => "You have left one or more fields blank."); if ($_GET["loginFailed"]) echo $reasons[$_GET["reason"]]; ?>
</form>
```

Also, make sure to `die()` or `exit()` when you use `header` to redirect the page, otherwise the rest of your script continues to run.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm reviewing all of your answers now and I'll post feedback when I get something working! I'm very new to PHP so figuring out what your fixes are doing is taking some time.

Comment: The rest of the script after `header` doesn't necessarily continue to run (and usually doesn't), but it is tehcnically possible to simply ignore the changed headers and not redirect (which causes the script to continue). So yes, stopping the script right after setting the header is strongly recommended.

Comment: Hi Travesty3. I understand your concept of using an array to output an error depending on what has caused it, but in the if($_GET["loginFailed"] I am getting an error saying that loginFailed is an undefined index. Where is this condition coming from?

Comment: That's a PHP **notice**, rather than an **error**. It means that you have your error_reporting setting in your php.ini set to show notices. Try `if (isset($_GET["loginFailed"]))` instead.

Comment: Still nothing! Where is the "loginFailed" condition coming from? What is if(isset($_GET["loginFailed"])) checking and how?

Comment: You need to modify your checklogin.php to redirect to the URL `index.html?loginFailed=true&reason=password`. This is where "loginFailed" comes from. `if(isset($_GET["loginFailed"]))` checks to see if the parameter 'loginFailed' was set in the URL, which it should be if you modify your checklogin.php script as stated above.

Comment: Excellent! This is working like charm so far, thanks Travesty :)

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it worked. If this is the solution you went with, then please mark this as your accepted solution using the check mark under the voting arrows for this solution. Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick follow up question: I thought `$_GET` was used to collect values in a form with `method="get`. What is `$_GET` doing here? It seems that its checking if `loginFailed` is in the URL?

Comment: `$_GET` is used to get parameters from the querystring section of the URL. Submitting a form with `method="get"` will append the form values to the URL. Try creating a form with `method="get"` and submit the form and then look at your URL. You will see the form variables there in the URL.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is, redirect back to your page if data is invalid. Put errors into session and display them on page:

e.g.:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['Login.Error'])  { echo $_SESSION['Login.Error'];
 unset($_SESSION['Login.Error']); } ?>
<form ....
```

and your error will be visible on page.

In your PHP

```
 $_SESSION["Login.Error"] = 'Invalid credentials';//redirect back to your login page
```

Comment: Thanks all, I'm reviewing all of your answers now and I'll post feedback when I get something working! I'm very new to PHP so figuring out what your fixes are doing is taking some time.

Comment: This is a great solution. It is both compatible with PRG and avoids to append error info to the query string.

Answer (score 2):

In checklogin.php, if the user enters a wrong username or password, use the code like this:

```
echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
echo "alert('Username or Password was incorrect!');\n";
echo "window.location='login.php'";
echo "</script>";
```

It will pop up the error message at the same page (login page), instead of going to a blank PHP page.

Comment: This is working (I used it as a temporal solution). But I need an elegant solution than this.

Comment: @AlpiGC what is your meaning for elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to make your index.html page a PHP page, and have the form submit to itself, i.e. to index.php.  In this way, you your index page can do the login check for the form values and display the output of the page appropriately, or use headers to redirect if everything validates.

It's hard to tell the effect that your attempt may have had without seeing it in the full context, but the gist of the situation is you need the form to submit to itself and handle it's login processing.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm reviewing all of your answers now and I'll post feedback when I get something working! I'm very new to PHP so figuring out what your fixes are doing is taking some time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386301/login-form-redirecting-back-to-itself-on-submit

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want/need to integrate it with jQuery or some other Javascript/AJAX library
to make things more presentable. jQuery has an plugin for form validation that's is very easy to integrate to your project (obviously jQuery library is minimum requirement).
[jQuery site](http://jquery.com/) and
[jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).
You may also consider using a PHP Framework like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) which is also has a very helpful form validation library. CodeIgniter is scary at the beginning (like all MVC based programming library/framework) but it's worth it. you can watch some tutorials on netTuts+ they've created a series of tutorials called [CodeIgniter From Scratch](http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/), is not from the latest version but is easy to adapt.